# Updating db with select options (Laravel 4)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table displayed with data from db where in the status column i have left an option to change the status using the select. I want to be able to update just the 'status' column by changing the options and i want to be able to change multiple rows with one button. Previously i can change but i have to have a button for each row.

//The view code for the status column is as follow:

```
  <td>
                    <select class="btn pull-left" name="status[]" id="status[]" onchange="javascript:changeStatus('{{$row->id}}','{{$arr}}')">
                        <option>{{ $row->status }}</option>
                        <option>Eligible</option>
                        <option>Not Eligible</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <input name="recordid[]" id="recordid[]" type="hidden">
            <?php $arr++;?>
            @endforeach
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function changeStatus(id,arr){
                //alert(id);
               // $('#recordid['+arr+]').val(id);
                // $("input[name='recordid']").eq(1).val(id);
                 $('[id^=recordid]').eq(arr).val(id);
                        // document.status.submit();
                }
            </script>
```

//The controller

```
 public function select(){

        $status = Input::get('status');
        $id = Input::get('recordid');
//        print_r($id);
//       print_r($status);exit;
        $user = User::find($id);
       If (isset($status)){
            $user->status = $status;
            $user->save();
        }
        return View::make('search')->with('status',$status);
    }
```

From the print_r of id and status i will get this output if i change the options with get the id too as in the code below where i change the status in the array one and two.

Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => [3] => ) Array ( [0] => Volunteer [1] => Volunteer [2] => Volunteer [3] => Eligible )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update multiple records liker this:

```
User::>whereIn('id', $id)->update(['status' => $status]);
```

Full method:

```
public function select(){
    $status = Input::get('status');
    $id = Input::get('recordid');

    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($status) - 1; $i++) {
         User::where('id', $id[$i])->update(['status' => $status[$i]]);
    // Even better
    // User::find($id[$i])->update(['status' => $status[$i]]);
    }

    return View::make('search')->with('status',$status);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Viktor. I applied that but now I got this error though when I print $status or the $id I got the array. 
Error: preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array

Comment: @EgzonnaGerguri, I changed my anwer. Try this variant.

Comment: done that but i am getting another error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\FYP Project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 311 and defined

Comment: @EgzonnaGerguri, my bad. Fixed, try one more time, please.)

Comment: It is working just like before, just that now is changing just the first row after that no more. Still i can not update multiple rows.

Comment: If I do this:
 $var=User::where('id', $id[$i])->update(['status' => $status[$i]]);
 print_r($var);exit; I am getting just 1.

Comment: @EgzonnaGerguri, check one more time, please.
Because update method return bool|int. Your update was successful, that's why you got 1.

Comment: It will only update the first row always, but cant change anything in the rest.

Comment: @EgzonnaGerguri, It's difficult to write code here. I missed parameter in count(). Sorry about that, I gust want to help. Try that method again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working thougt now looking for the following error: Undefined offset: 4. However, it is sawing multiple data which is what i needed.

Comment: @EgzonnaGerguri, fixed offset. I hope this code will work good.)

Comment: @EgzonnaGerguri, I'm glad to help. Good luck!)